Variable localisation in Table
I'm trying to understand Mathematica's behavior when creating a Table based on a given list of variables. I'm using a dummy variable to iterate through the list, and I want to make sure that Mathematica properly localizes this variable so that its name does not affect the result. When I run this
lst = {a, b};
Table[f[x], {x, lst}]
Table[f[a], {a, lst}]
Table[f[b], {b, lst}]

the output is always {f[a], f[b]}, as expected. This means that the name of the dummy variable doesn't matter and it is correctly localized.
However, when I test this for creating a 2-dimensional array
lst = {a, b};
Table[f[x, y], {x, lst}, {y, lst}]
Table[f[x, b], {x, lst}, {b, lst}]
Table[f[a, y], {a, lst}, {y, lst}]
Table[f[a, b], {a, lst}, {b, lst}]

things suddenly get strange because the output now depends on the variable names:
{{f[a, a], f[a, b]}, {f[b, a], f[b, b]}}
{{f[a, a], f[a, b]}, {f[a, a], f[b, b]}}
{{f[a, a], f[a, b]}, {f[b, b], f[b, b]}}
{{f[a, a], f[a, b]}, {f[b, b], f[b, b]}}

Only the first line is as expected but the last three are off in the third entry.
I'm wondering whether this is a bug (I'm using Mathematica 14.1.0.0). If this is indeed the correct behavior, can somebody explain what is happening internally?

@Szabolcs I do not think so since the second iterator can depend on the first iterator if we use the same name of a variable.

@azerbajdzan You are right, it makes sense. I got confused about dynamic scoping. I'm deleting my first comment.

@Szabolcs I was confused too, sometimes things are convoluted.

I think nothing strange happens here. If you use the same name in second iterator as in first iterator, then the second iterator depends on the values of first iterator.
Simple example - m in {n, m, 2} is dependent on value of m in {m, 1, 2}.
Table[{m, n}, {m, 1, 2}, {n, m, 2}]


{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{2, 2}}}

Same holds if we are not iterating over range but over list. Vaule of m in {n, {m, 2}}] depends on value of m in {m, {1, 2}}.
Table[{m, n}, {m, {1, 2}}, {n, {m, 2}}]


{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}}


Per the docs, in support of your answer: "Table[expr,Subscript[spec, 1],Subscript[spec, 2]] is effectively equivalent to Table[Table[expr,Subscript[spec, 2]],Subscript[spec, 1]]." (See Details section.)

Also, it is rather the purpose of Block[vars, code] to allow users to pass code that depends on vars in this way. ("Table effectively uses Block....") I remember learning or figuring out that if I needed a truly localized iterator in Table[], I needed to do something like Module[{i}, Table[f[i], {i, i1, i2}]].

Thanks! I can use Module[{a, b}, Table[f[a, b], {a, lst}, {b, lst}]] to properly localize the iterators.
